Recibo el siguiente Error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')" al usar la libreria stl para convertir un objeto a stl
Porfavor necesito ayuda porque estoy en un proyecto de nodejs con exprees y usando la libreria stl (https://www.npmjs.com/package/stl) version 1.1.1, ademas de la biblioteca stl estoy usando express para hacer una api, con la que me estoy conectando atraves de webpack, y la libreria stl me esta dando el siguiente error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
    at computeNormal (C:\Users\Joaquin Strada\Documents\node js\fusionar stl\node_modules\stl\stl.js:19:9)
    at Object.fromObject (C:\Users\Joaquin Strada\Documents\node js\fusionar stl\node_modules\stl\stl.js:69:33)
    at convertPointsToStl (C:\Users\Joaquin Strada\Documents\node js\fusionar stl\api\utils\/stl.js:35:26)

Y no puedo depurar donde esta el error. Les dejo mi codigo a continuacion:
import stl from 'stl'

export const parseStl = stlBuffer => {
    const { facets } = stl.toObject(stlBuffer)

    return facets.map(({ normal, verts }) => verts.map(([x, y, z]) => ({
        x: normal[0] * x,
        y: normal[1] * y,
        z: normal[2] * z
    }))).flat()
}

export const convertPointsToStl = pointsStl => {
    const heights = pointsStl.map(pointStl => pointStl.z).filter((height, index, array) => array.indexOf(height) === index)
    const facets = []

    for (let i = 0; i < heights.length; i++) {
        const height = heights[i];
        const verts = pointsStl.filter(point => point.z === height).map(point => ([
            point.x,
            point.y,
            point.z
        ]))

        facets.push({
            verts
        })
    }

    const stlJson = {
        description: 'Nuevo stl',
        facets
    }

    const stlAscii = stl.fromObject(stlJson, false)
    console.log(stlAscii);

    return {
        stlJson
    }
}

Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar, desde ya gracias!!!!

en typescript yo lo haría así: const heights = pointsStl?.map(pointStl => pointStl.z)?.filter((height, index, array) => array.indexOf(height) === index)||[] lo que daría como equivalente en js  const heights = ((_a = pointsStl === null || pointsStl === void 0 ? void 0 : pointsStl.map(pointStl => pointStl.z)) === null || _a === void 0 ? void 0 : _a.filter((height, index, array) => array.indexOf(height) === index)) || []; pruébalo y nos cuentas

Me sigue dando el mismo error no puede ser un problema de la biblioteca????, Aclaro no estoy usando typescript, y cuando veo el array por consola esta todo bien, no tiene ningún error!!!!

No, ese error es el equivalente a un null pointer exception, así que sin saber que hay exactamente en stl.js en la línea 35 caracter número 26 no sabría como ayudarte, tal vez quieras actualziar la información de la pregunta con esa información porque esencialmente estás tratando de llamar un método de un objeto que es undefined o nulo

En la linea 35, esta la declaracion del objeto que se pasa a la funcion. const stlJson = {         description: 'Nuevo stl',         facets     } y ya lo depure y esta perfecto segun la libreria.
